# Create Fluid Background Image with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I am trying to build a simple fluid image that can resize based on screen size.

But I am having trouble to get the image smaller when the width of the browser gets smaller.

HTML:

```
<main>
    <section class="slider-ctn">
        <figure class="logo"></figure>
    </section>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
.slider-ctn figure.logo {
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url('../Images/logo.200x100.png');
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a `jsfiddle` snippet.

Comment: I'm trying out a solution with calc.  I'll post it in a bit if it works out.

Comment: Didn't use calc.  Decided on vw units instead.  Answer posted below.  Hope it helps.

Comment: @AmrAly Hi, I can create a jsfiddle but the code is just that, nothing else.

Comment: @Patrick  you are right it's not needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the `background-size` to `100% 100%` or `cover` the image will stretch to fit the container. Remove the width (or restrict the width by setting the parent's width) and set `height: 0; padding-top: 50%` on the figure to make the height of the figure half of the width, so the aspect ratio will match the image and be fluid.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
.slider-ctn {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
.slider-ctn figure.logo {
  background: url('https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff') top left no-repeat;
  height: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="slider-ctn">
    <figure class="logo"></figure>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Hi thank! I have tested your code but what happens is that I does not allow to resize smaller then the width of the image (200px), but I would like to allow that. I don't want to stop the resize at the width of the image. But I found out something strange, when I use the Toggle Device Bar from Chrome and I try to resize it, it works fine, but when I disable the TDB it does not resize.

Comment: @Patrick then all you have to do is remove the width on `.slider-ctn`... then it will scale to whatever the device width is. Maybe you want to set that as a `max-width`?

Comment: I am trying TriForce's solution that includes max-width and it seems to work

Comment: I have been testing all the solutions and yours seems to be the best. For example, if I have a 500px picture's height, when I resize the image to a smaller size, the image gets smaller but the space of the element remains 500px height, which pushes everything down. With yours, it seems that the elements remains together with no space between them. I just don't understand the height: 0 and the padding-top: 50%, can you explain more in detail what it does please? And why top left and not top center? Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick use `top center` if that works for you. I just picked something, and `top left` is the default. A padding-top (or bottom) of 50% means 50% of the width. Since your image is 200x100, you want the height to be half of the width, meaning you use 50% padding.

Comment: Sorry, I keep not understanding how creating a padding-top and a height 0 gets everything to work correctly :( In my project, the final image is 776x531...

Comment: @patrick then use 68.42783505% padding. https://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size - only available on >= IE11 :(

Comment: @Patrick no, click "show all" and look again. It's supported in >= ie8

Comment: ah ok. There is still people with IE8 but I don't know if it's a condition

Comment: @Patrick "a condition"? Look in the top/right of that page, the property has 97% support.

Comment: I have selected your answer because I am going to use it in my project. I have fully understand the concept and it works nice. I am creating a mobile first website, and I would like just to ask you, for the smaller image size and to avoid the browser from loading it in a Desktop, should I put the CSS Background image of the mobile in a media query just for mobile size? Thank you again for all your help and fast answer.

Comment: @Patrick you're welcome. Yeah just use the desktop image in the desktop CSS and the mobile image in the mobile `@media` query.

Comment: Ok Great! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Michael, I have a background image of 320x600px (for a responsive mobile version size), how do I apply your method?

Comment: @Patrick `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` of `187.5%` (height / width or 600 / 320 1.875 or 187.5%)

Comment: Ok, great! Thank you ;)

Comment: @Patrick np. I learned from this article, the 2nd entry "iframe <video> youtube, etc" https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to your `head` tag with this code :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! I was already using this tag. But I found out something strange,  when I use the Toggle Device Bar from Chrome and I try to resize it, it works fine, but when I disable the TDB it does not resize.

Comment: Use flex-box , or grid in your css

Answer (score 1):

You should add `contain` as background-size to your CSS:

```
.slider-ctn figure.logo {
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url('../Images/logo.200x100.png');
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  width: 200px;
  max-width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Don't forgot to add `position` and `repeat` to background properties everytime when you use background images.

Also I added `max-width` to fit within the parent container if it is smaller than the logo container.

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/fuy3mxb1/)

> **NOTE:** Don't use `cover` in background-size because that will cut your
>   logo to fit only within `width` limits, `contain` will fit `width` and
>   `height`.

Comment: Hi, thank! And why do you use the display:inline-block; ?

Comment: It is out of habit, always i set a display method, because sometimes the containers arent show properly in some navigators. `display:inline-block` makes u to get the alignment from the parent div (if has align left,center,right), `display:block` will works like `float `(left or right only), but also u can "center align" with with `margin:auto` if u want

Comment: I tried to remove margin:auto; and the result is the same thanks to the center center position. I am not able is to resize an image to a smaller viewport then 300px with an image of 1280x800, any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Another option using vw units and contain.

If you know the aspect ratio of your image you can use vw (view width) as your units for width and height.

I am using an image that has a 4x3 aspect ratio.  If I want the width to always be 80% of the screen I will use 80vw.  Then, my height will be 3/4 of my width, or 60vw.

Then be sure to use contain for your background sizing.

Try this css and see if it satisfies your needs:

`.slider-ctn figure.logo {
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 60vw;
  border: 5px solid red;
}`

Comment: Hi thank, but it seems a complex operation to do for each image, I would prefer a solution that I could use for every image.

Answer (score 1):

I think setting up the max-width of the image to 100% should do the trick.

```
.slider-ctn figure.logo {
  background-image: url('../Images/logo.200x100.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks but it's not working, it stays with the original size

Comment: Hey @Patrick, yes that because I didn't realise it was a background-image. I edited the code snippet.

Comment: Ok, let me test it. Thanks.

Comment: With your solution, I am having a problem, when the image reduce from his initial size, it creates an empty space like a margin-top and a margin-bottom, but I don't want am empty space before. But if I remove the center property, the image gets centered at the left, is it possible to solve this?

Comment: I made some changes in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkga6zms/19/) but didn't got where actually the problem is. You can make changes to the Fiddle as well if you want, in order to show some more information. For example, what are the styles of the parent container.

Comment: I give an example, I use figure and figcaption for the image, and when I reduce the image in width, the height keeps his original size of the image and pushes down the figcaption